# Jquery: Clone inside iteration (.each) scrambles html structure

Tags: jquery, html, clone, structure, each

I have a snip of code that I cannot seem to fix. Everything works fine if I do not iterate through the function, or if I do not clone. When I put them together, the structure of the divs gets scrambled.

Before any code, I start with:

```
<div class="origin"></div>
```

Then I write some script to add html, which should be structured like this:
Code:

```
<div id="id0">
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="origin"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="viewport"></div>
<div id="id1">
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="origin"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="viewport"></div>
```

It starts fine, but if you uncomment the two lines below, the second div with ID is now inside the previous viewport, instead of wrapped around "origin".  I'm trying to copy the images and maybe captions, inside each "origin" to inside its own viewport (with two surrounding divs on the images).

The code:

```
function writeGallery(i) {
    var startDiv = $("div.origin:eq("+i+")");
    startDiv.wrap('<div class="scroller"></div>');  
    startDiv.parent().wrap ('<div id="id' + i + '" />');
    var horizThumbwrap      = startDiv.parent().parent();
    horizThumbwrap.append ('<a href="#"></a>');
    horizThumbwrap.after ('<div class="viewport" />');

    //var horizViewport        = startDiv.parent().parent().next(".viewport");
    //startDiv.clone().appendTo(horizViewport);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

$("div.origin").each(function(index) {
writeGallery (index);
});

$('#result').text($('#container').html());
});
```

**The code here in fiddle (uncomment 2 lines to see mess): http://jsfiddle.net/AjSnx/**

The only thing I can think of is to rewrite it in various ways and just hope I hit on something that works.  But since it's my first jQuery project, I'd like to understand what I've done wrong here, too.

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: you are appending the cloned data to `horizViewport` which is undefined.

Comment: It works in the first iteration -- did you uncomment both lines?  I don't see how it could work even once if it's undefined.  Or umm, I suppose it might, I don't understand enough to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside each loop, you are selecting the `.origin` elements using `:eq()`. However, in each loop you create another `<div class="origin" />`. So in the following loop you are selecting the `<div>` that you just created using `.clone()` and **not the `<div>` that was there from the beginning**. To fix this, use the second argument passed to the function that is called by `.each()`. It contains the current element that was matched in the beginning (i.e. the element you intended to use inside the loop).

Please see [my update](http://jsfiddle.net/AjSnx/1/) for details. The HTML produced is this:

```
<div id="id0">
    <div class="scroller">
        <div class="origin"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="origin"></div>
</div>

<div id="id1">
    <div class="scroller">
        <div class="origin"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="origin"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! I am studying this but it looks like you fixed it, thanks so much. Now to try to understand.  :)

Comment: Thanks for that update Wolfram.  That's a noob mistake, eh?  I just learned alot from this, thanks. :)

Comment: Only because you get that element handed from jQuery so there is no need to select it again. Quite tricky to catch though. You can also shorten your code even more, see [Raminson's answer for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11484777/95033).

Answer (score 0):

If i don't got it completely backwards, you're trying to put the contents of the origin-div ti the viewport-div where origin is startDiv, right?

You might need not to clone something, maybe just fill the innerHTML of the viewport with innerHTML of origin

```
startDiv.closest('.viewport').html( startDiv.html() );
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks Max, that's a useful idea to keep. :)

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative you can try this:

```
   $("div.origin").each(function(i) {
       $(this).wrap('<div id="id'+i+'><div class="scroller"></div></div>')
       $(this).after('<a href="#"></a><div class="viewport"></div>')     
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AjSnx/3/

Comment: I didn't realize jQuery was smart enough to wrap twice, nice tip!